# Why does my code compile with -fno-exceptions in Qt Creator when I try to use exceptions?

Tags: c++, qt

In the project .pro file I've specified:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fno-exceptions
```

Yet I'm able to throw exceptions in my app. Any thoughts on that?

Example: This shouldn't work, but it works

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int c, char**v)
{
    QApplication app(c,v);
    try
    {
        throw 1;
    }
    catch(int i)
    {

    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Qt library doesn`t use exceptions.

Comment: What's the question? Is the question, "Why does my code compile, I expected it to fail since I'm incorrectly trying to throw an exception in code that I'm attempting to compile with -fno-exceptions?"? Or is the question, "how do I correctly link my exception-using code with Qt?"? "Any thoughts on that" is inappropriately broad for SO, it's not here to poll people's personal reaction to a given text ;-)

Comment: @smallB By "I am able to throw exceptions" you mean that they are correctly dispatched (`catch` is working, stack unwinding is happening etc) or that you are able to compile and crash your application?

Comment: @AzzA yes, I AM ABLE TO USE THEM

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not turn off exceptions by setting `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` because this options is handled by `CONFIG`. You should use

```
CONFIG-=exceptions
```

to turn them off.

See the g++ args when you have neither `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` nor `CONFIG` settings changed:

```
g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall <...> main.cpp
```

Now, let's set `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`: get

```
g++ -c -fno-exceptions -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall <...> main.cpp
```

Ooops, we get our `-fno-exceptions` is overridden by `CONFIG`'s `-fexceptions`.
Now, let's set `CONFIG`:

```
g++ -c -O2 -frtti -Wall -fno-exceptions <...> main.cpp
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `G:/proj/ingeritance'
main.cpp: In function 'int qMain(int, char**)':
main.cpp:22:15: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [release/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [release] Error 2
```

Oh! compilation error!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit confused by the question.

If you have (or link to) code that throws exceptions, you can't just magically make them go away by building your code with `-fno-exceptions`. The flag affects the generation of code necessary to support `try` and `catch`, more than the code that actually throws exceptions.

See [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html#intro.using.exception.no) for details. The documentation says:

> In sum, valid C++ code with exception handling is transformed into a dialect without exception handling.

So, it seems more as if the compiler more or less causes the exception-handling (and throwing) code to "go away", rather than detect its use and flag an error. The latter seems to be what you're expecting, but that expectation is, then, simply wrong.

Comment: +1, Perhaps more pertinent than the library documentation you linked, here is [the code generator options page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fexceptions-2164).

Answer (score 2):

try to use both of the following

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -fno-exceptions

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -fno-exceptions
```